# Laravel 4: Publishing a Package's Assets

Tags: php, laravel-4

How to publish package assets? I've found a tutorial here: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/279

But when I tried to publish assets from my workbench, I get this error:

```
[RuntimeException]         
 Unable to publish assets.  

asset:publish [--bench[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [package]
```

My command code is:

```
php artisan asset:publish --bench=Mypackage
```

How can I get my package assets to be published.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your package definition have files in the `/assets` folder?

Comment: I don't find any assets folder in workbench directory. Isn't that it take files from the public folder in the package to publish it?

Answer (score 6):

When you want to publish assets that are developed and stored in your workbench you should use the `--bench` flag. In your case you want to publish a package in the vendor folder then provide "myVendor/myPackage".

Publishing assets from a vendor package

```
php artisan asset:publish "vendor/package"
```

Publishing assets from a workbench package

```
php artisan asset:publish --bench="vendor/package"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the answer! Can't make it any clearer then this.

Comment: Normally when you are answering to something, it's nice to say what part of the code (in the question) was wrong, or what is that part of the question in particular that you're correcting. So in your answer, you can brief a little bit about why "`vendor/package`" is the main trick of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give an example with Twitter Bootstrap Package.

If you want to publish your assets in the folder "public/packages" :

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist"
```

If you want to publish your assets in the folder "public/" :

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist" "../"
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the Workbench to prepare your own package for use in Laravel.

There is a directory structure for where to place your files:

```
/src
    /Vendor
        /Package
            PackageServiceProvider.php
    /config
    /lang
    /migrations
    /views
/tests
```

/public <---- the folder in question here

When preparing your package, any files that need to be accessible from the web server like imgs/css/js files (or `assets` as they are typically called in web apps) are put here.

Then when you enter the command:

```
php artisan asset:publish --bench=Mypackage
```

it will deploy those files into

```
/approot
/public
    /vendor/package/
```

more info here:  http://laravel.com/docs/packages

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to copy Twitter Bootstrap (SASS version) for me worked only:

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor\twbs\bootstrap-sass\assets"  .
```

it copied assets folder content (3 directories) to `public/packages`.

When I had no `.` at the end there was no message and nothing was copied.

And when I omitted `assets` directory in the command the whole `vendor\twbs\bootstrap-sass` directory content was copied to `public` directory what is of course unnecessary