# How to load CSS and JS from theme directory in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would be very happy if someone could help me!
I'm a beginner with Laravel and started building an application in which I will use themes.
I want to my CSS files to be stored in "/path-to-theme/img/" folder.
I found some examples refering on CSS loading, but is not what I need.

There is what I found:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

To see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954758/how-to-load-view-from-alternative-directory-in-laravel-4) for more information.
What should I do to load CSS from the "/path-to-theme/img/" instead of "/public" folder.

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: The themes in the post you are referring to are HTML templates. The CSS files have to be located in the `public` folder

Answer (score 2):

All Assets must be located in the `public` directory. Within that directory you can use any folder structure you might want to use eg. `public/path-to-theme/etc`.

There might be an other solution (didn't test it), **but its a bit messy**.

You could create an `AssetsController` and in that controller load the files based on the template settings. I'm not sure how your situation is exactly but I can immagine the following. A user has a preference for a theme (stored in the users table in the DB). In `app.php` you could create a `template` config variable. The value of this variable is the default theme that will be used if not a specific theme is set (by the user for example or based on an input field or get parameter (or whatever)).

```
array(
   'theme' => 'default',
),
```

In the AssetsController you cold create a getCss action and load the theme corrosponding to the css you need:

```
public function getCss() {

    $theme = Config::get('app.theme');
    return file_get_contents($theme.'/stylesheet.css');
}
```

Inside `routes.php` you create the following route

```
Route::get('stylesheet.css', array('uses' => 'AssetsController@getCss'));
```

To load your css in your view file you add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::action('AssetsController@getCss') }}">
```

This works for the default theme. If you want to load the user specific theme preferences you can do that in a filter (`filters.php`), for example in the auth filter or a custom filter in filters.php (you should append that filter name to the original routes of the pages you want to display).

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    Config::set('app.theme', Auth::user()->theme);
});
```

This only works if the user is logged in. But in a different filter you could check if a different parameter is set (an get, post or session variable for example).

Hope this might help.

Comment: Ok MThomas, I created an controller named **`CssController`** in wich I have a method **`loadCss()`**, I created a route **`Route::get('style.css', 'CssController@loadCss');`** - all works ok when I access css file _lux-apps/style.css_. However... there is an another problem - I want to my css files to be accessed like here: _lux_apps.ru/css/style.css_, I created a route **`Route::get('css/style.css', 'CssController@loadCss');`** and **IT DOESN'T WORK!!!** :( Why so? can you help me?

Comment: Frist of all, I meant that the solution using the controller is a bit messy, the proper way would be storing your files in public/theme/css. Do all other routes function well, it sounds like your Apache mod rewrite is not configured correct or your using the wrong htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have switched to Laravel 5 you can try my package with features like:

- Views & Asset seperation in theme folders
- Theme inheritence: Extend any theme and create Theme hierarcies

Try it here: [igaster/laravel-theme](https://github.com/igaster/laravel-theme)

Answer (score 0):

Assets must published to `public` folder. You can publish the assets using something like this from your `command prompt/terminal`:

```
php artisan asset:publish

php artisan asset:publish vendor/package

php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor/package"
```

Use the appropriate one. [Check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-assets) on `Laravel` website and another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596140/laravel-4-publishing-a-packages-assets).